# Design Pattern for list of Multiple data type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-structures

I have data set like below.

```
Name     |  Type   | OptionType   | Value
--------------------------------------------
Count    | int     | null         | 20
volume   | double  | null         | 10.2
customer | string  | null         | tim
direction| option  | Left, Right  | Left
shape    | option  | rect, circle | rect
…        |   …     | …            | …
```

(not only 5. so many data set)

What is the best design pattern or data structure  to handle data set ?

---

I try think that below…

```
Dictionary <name, object> dataDictionary;

// add
dataDictionary.Add("count", (int)20);
dataDictionary.Add("volume", (double)10.2);
dataDictionary.Add("customer", "tim");
dataDictionary.Add("direction", enumDirection.Left);
dataDictionary.Add("shape", enumShape.Rect);

// get - **I have to know data type….**
int count = (int)dataDictionary["count"];
double volume = (double)dataDictionary["volume"] ;
string customer = (string)dataDictionary["customer"];
enumDirection eDirection = (enumDirection)dataDictionary["direction"];
```

Is anything better?

Comment: What's preventing you from defining a class to contain your data?

Comment: Defining a class is ok. At the fist time, I think inherited class. but I think that is same method using dictionary.

Comment: why can't you user an anonymous type if what you fear is implementing a class?

Comment: Agree w/ Anthony, I would want a really compelling case to not use a class.  Unless you're looking for a lot of boxing and unboxing and the overhead of a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot. I would take a class.